# How could i get the name of a role in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created an add role command. It works fine but my problem is that it works only with the id of the role. I was wondering how could I somehow convert the id of the role to the name of the role.
**This is the code.**

```
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def addrole(self, ctx, member: discord.Member,rolename):
        if member is None:
            member=ctx.author
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=rolename)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}was added {rolename}")
```

Any help is appreciated.edit

### **solution**

I made use of the 2 comments and created this command which works perfectly.

````py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def addrole(self, ctx, role: discord.Role, member: discord.Member=None):
        if member is None:
            member=ctx.author
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} was added {role}")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your `rolename` variable as a `discord.Role` and make use of the implicit [role converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.RoleConverter) that will be applied, just like what happens to your `member` object. Your function would look something like this:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def addrole(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} was added {rolename}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use role converter just like you used member converter. You can pass `role: discord.Role` in arguments. Then, you just have to mention the role.

Also, you have to assign a default value `None` to the `member` argument in order to check if it's `None`.

```py
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def addrole(self, ctx, role: discord.Role, member: discord.Member=None):
    if not member:
        member=ctx.author
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}was added {role.name}")
```

## References

- [`RoleConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.RoleConverter)
- [`discord.Role.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.name)

Comment: This will error on you because a positional argument follows a keyword argument. OP would have to change the argument order to make the member optional

Comment: It errored on the: role: discord.Role.So the new command now has the discord.role first and then the member: discord.Member=None,as you can see in the solution.TY for helping.